# How to remove broken menu links from Centos

Tags: centos, gnome

http://imtp.me/50k001tmy

Please check this link, I am trying to remove a broken link from Centos. I removed netbeans7.3.desktop file also but I think I am missing something.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can easily edit the GNOME menu with the package `alacarte`. Most times, it is already installed on your system. Here is a How-To: http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Configuring_the_CentOS_6_Desktop_Menu_System

[From the How-To](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Configuring_the_CentOS_6_Desktop_Menu_System#Adding_and_Deleting_a_Menu_Item):

> A menu item may be hidden or deleted entirely. Hide a menu item simply by turning off the toggle next to the item in the menu configuration dialog. Delete an item by right clicking it in the menu configuration dialog and selecting Delete from the popup menu.

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to find out where to do the physical changes. But this is good too.